# how to change a variable after data changes in swift

Tags: swift, api, parsing, model

I am using an API to learn how API's work and I wrote a function that takes data from the web and parses it to my model but when I want to print anything from that model it does not work except it is in my function.

```
import UIKit

class MovieDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedMovie : Int?
    var movieDetail : MovieDetailModel? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getMovioesDetail(url: "\(URLs().baseURL)/movie/\(selectedMovie!)\(URLs().API_key)")
    print(movieDetail?.backdrop_path)
    // It does not print the path
}

//MARK: - Functions

func getMovioesDetail (url: String) {
    WebServices().get(url) { (type, model : MovieDetailModel?) in
        switch type {
        case .Succeed :
            self.movieDetail = model
            print(self.movieDetail?.backdrop_path)
            // It prints the path
        case .Failed : print("Failed")
        case .FailedDecode : print("FailedDecode")
        default : break
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @**Aaron Cyrman** stated, your function includes a web service call and the web service runs asynchronously, meaning that it is not known when you get a response.

That's why if you want to print out something or reload your tableview/collectionview, do that in case .Succeed; not right after calling your function.

Also you better do nil check of your model class after filling it.

Just to show an example:

```
case .Succeed:
    self.movieDetail = model
    if self.movieDetail != nil{
        print(movieDetail!.backdrop_path)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
break
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about `WebServices` is difficult to know.

I'm guessing the `WebServices().get(url)` runs asynchronous in a different thread, so the closure is being call when the API request returns data and that's why the print works.

When you are executing code in `viewDidLoad` is running on the main thread. Immediately after the `getMovioesDetail` call, `print(movieDetail?.backdrop_path)` is executed and most likely `movieDetail` is still `nil` since the `WebService` hasn't finish.

To be certain change:

```
print(movieDetail?.backdrop_path)
```

with this:

```
print(movieDetail?.backdrop_path ?? "Movie detail not available yet")
```

If the web service runs very fast you will see the path printed two times, if not you will first the *Movie detail not available yet* and then the path.

Comment: I wrote `print(movieDetail?.backdrop_path ?? "Movie detail not available yet")`  and it prints Movie detail not available yet.

Comment: We can confirm now that the web service call it's async.  What is happening it's the expected behavior. It is a good practice to run in a different thread long running operations so the main thread doesn't get blocked. If you want to read about the subject there is plenty of resources, for instance on https://www.raywenderlich.com or https://www.swiftbysundell.com